# How to replace ties with NA in R

Tags: r, matrix

I am working on a function to return the column name of the largest value for each row. Something like:

```
colnames(x)[apply(x,1,which.max)]
```

However, before applying a function like this is there a straight forward and general way to replace ties with NA (or any other arbitrary letter etc.)?

I have the following matrix:

```
               0            1
 [1,] 5.000000e-01 0.5000000000
 [2,] 9.901501e-01 0.0098498779
 [3,] 9.981358e-01 0.0018641935
 [4,] 9.996753e-01 0.0003246823
 [5,] 9.998598e-01 0.0001402322
 [6,] 1.303731e-02 0.9869626938
 [7,] 1.157919e-03 0.9988420815
 [8,] 6.274074e-07 0.9999993726
 [9,] 1.659164e-07 0.9999998341
[10,] 6.517362e-08 0.9999999348
[11,] 8.951474e-06 0.9999910485
[12,] 5.070740e-06 0.9999949293
[13,] 1.278186e-07 0.9999998722
[14,] 9.914646e-08 0.9999999009
[15,] 7.058751e-08 0.9999999294
[16,] 2.847667e-09 0.9999999972
[17,] 1.675766e-08 0.9999999832
[18,] 2.172290e-06 0.9999978277
[19,] 4.964820e-06 0.9999950352
[20,] 1.333680e-07 0.9999998666
[21,] 2.087793e-07 0.9999997912
[22,] 2.358360e-06 0.9999976416
```

The first row has equal values for  variables which I would like to replace with NA. While this is simple for this particular example, I want to be able to replace all ties with NA where they occur in any size matrix i.e. in this matrix:

```
      1     2    3
[1,]  0.25  0.25  0.5
[2,]  0.3   0.3   0.3
```

all values would be replaced with NA except for [1,3]

I have looked at the function `which.max.simple()` which can deal with ties by replacing with NA but it doesn't appear to work any more, and all other methods of dealing with ties don't address my issue

I hope that makes sense

Thanks,
C

Comment: Trying to look for exact matches with floating point numbers doesn't always work the way you think it does. See [why aren't these numbers equal](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9508518/why-are-these-numbers-not-equal)

Comment: If you replace all ties with NA and and tied value happens to be the maximum in the row, how would you address this scenario

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a simple approach to replace any row-wise duplicated values with `NA` in a matrix `m`:

```
is.na(m) <- t(apply(m, 1, FUN = function(x) {
               duplicated(x) | duplicated(x, fromLast = TRUE)}))
```

But consider the following notes:

**1)** be extra careful when comparing floating point numbers for equality (see [Why are these numbers not equal?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9508518/));

**2)** depending on your ultimate target, there may be simpler ways than replacing duplicated in your data (since it seems that you are only interested in column names); and

**3)** if you are going to replace values in a numeric matrix, don't use arbitrary characters for replacement since that will convert your whole matrix to character class (replacement with `NA` is not a problem)